# Are there laptops with extremely high battery capacity?

Tags: laptop, battery-life, battery

I noticed that most laptops have batteries that have under 100 Wh of battery capacity. Usually this is fine and can last for hours if you aren't pushing the machine too hard, but I'm wondering if there are laptops that can last for hours even when doing extremely intensive computations.

Are there laptops with, say, 0.5 to 1 kWh worth of battery capacity? Weight is not a concern.

Comment: Probably not, due to safety considerations. Transport by air would be problematical. That said, there are power banks with AC outlets that could supplement the battery, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Omars-40200mAh-Portable-Universal-Compatible/dp/B07D9KZ4W3 .

Comment: Or depending on the laptop, if they have USB-C charging, you could get something slightly smaller but use USB-C to charge the laptop - something like this https://www.anker.com/store/powercore-speed-20000-pd/B1275011

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are Panasonic's Toughbooks. They are one of the most durable laptops out there. And yes, the battery lasts quite a while. If one battery is not enough for you, it also has interchangeable batteries usable through slots on the side. It is a bit expensive though.

E.g. a Panasonic Toughbook CF-33, which came to life around 2017 is about $3,599

[Here's a video of Linus Tech Tips reviewing the latest one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7rt6BZYscs)